# What is the proper angular keycloak version to use with keycloak-js 18.0.0 while I have angular-js 1.6.0 in my application?

Tags: angular, angularjs, keycloak, keycloak-js

When a user attempts logout/SIGNOUT from GUI using the SIGNOUT button provided in GUI, SIGNOUT is not happening and user gets an error page stating ‘Invalid parameter: redirect_uri’

Angular-js: 1.6.0
keyCloak: 18.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no angular keycloak module for AngularJS as it is considered pretty old nowadays. You have to install keycloak-js and use it instead

Comment: resolved the logout issue by upgrading keycloak to 18.0.1 version

Comment: @Deshan,I am attempting to integrate Keycloak with my AngularJS 1.8 application. However, I am encountering a $injector error every time. It is not redirecting to the Keycloak login page when I hit the URL in the browser.
It will be very if you provide me any sample code , document keycloak for angular JS. 1.x version 

Thanks Ranjan